# Do I have to put "to" or not?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm a bit fuzzy as to whether I should put *to* in the following sentence or not.

> Why not (to) try natural remedies first?

Comment: The answer is no, don't put `to` there. I don't have an explanation however.

Answer (score 2):

It depends slightly on your context. In a headline or title, yes. E.G.

> **Why not to light yourself on fire**
>
> 1. it would hurt quite a bit
> 2. you could inadvertently light other fires in your flailing

However, in present-tense speech or non-title contexts, the general answer (as noted by @gattsbr) is no:

> "Why not try natural remedies first?" she asked.

But here's a past-tense example where it is needed:

> I asked the doctor. He said (not) to try natural remedies first.

Similarly:

> Do you think the doctor will tell me to try natural remedies first?

Comment: You could note that *why not to light yourself on fire* is a phrase, not a complete sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Putting "to" in front of a verb makes it an "infinitive". An infinitive is generally used when we want to use a verb as the object of another verb.

Like I just did there. "I want ..." What do I want? I want "to use" something.

This is similar to the way a noun can be the object of a verb. I could say, "I want chocolate." What do I want? I want "chocolate". Here I want to perform an action. So "I want to use ..."

So for example, I might say, "I eat peas." "Eat" here is a simple, present tense verb. But "I like to eat peas." Now the "main" verb in the sentence is "like". What do I like? "I like to eat peas".

In your example, there is no other verb, so an infinitive is inappropriate. Don't include a "to".

Answer (score 0):

## Why to avoid that 'to,' and why not to.

To be, or not to be?  That is the question.  However, your sentence isn't actually a question.  It's a statement based off of internet lingo popularized through articles with headings like, "Top 10 reasons why not to kick an elephant."

1. Why not to [anything]? --*As a question, we expect certain words to follow the Why's, Where's, When's, etc.  We should then be able to drop the 'Why, Where, When, etc' and still have a valid question.*

   - Why not jump over the river? -> Don't jump over the river?
   - Why not to jump over the river? -> Don't to jump over the river?

     - *It ends up sounding like you forgot to conjugate the verb, leaving '**to [verb]**' for the reader to conjugate instead.*
2. Here's why not to try natural remedies first. OR Here's why to not try natural remedies first.

   - *As a statement, this... sounds odd, but it's perfectly acceptable, because the why can no longer be dropped, and '**not**' and '**to**' form a partnership becoming reversible.*
3. Why shouldn't I try natural remedies first?

   - *Is a valid question, and probably the best way to write it.*
4. Why not try herbal remedies first?

   - *Is  also a valid question.*

Answer (score 0):

In the special case when the sense of the sentence is to make a suggestion, the question word "why," and its negative, are almost always followed by the bare infinitive (without "to"):

> Why use salt instead of pepper?
>   Why talk when you can sing?
>   Why not use pepper instead of salt?